# Null-values for embedded objects are not accepted

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to persist an object containing an embedded one using Spring Data JDBC. And it is not saved because it does not pass a null-check.

I created an outer class to persist.

```
data class Outer(
    @Id 
    val id: Long,

    val value: String,

    @Embedded 
    inner: Inner? = null
)
```

```
data class Inner(
    val innerValue1: String,
    val innerValue2: String
)
```

In the DB I would like to have only one table for `Outer` which contains fields `id`, `value`, `inner_value_1` and `inner_value_2`. That's why I put `@Embedded` annotation on the `inner`-field.

`id` and `value` should be obligatory fields. `innver_value_1` and `invver_value_2` might be null,

The problem appears when I try to save null-inner object (which is nullable both in Kotlin and in the DB).

```
val outer = Outer(15, "value")

repo.save(outer) //throws an exception
```

The saving to repo operation throws an exception cause expects inner not to be null:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.verifyBeanType(BasicPersistentEntity.java:550)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:453)
```

The difficulty is that in Kotlin I cannot pass an object with null-valued-fields (because they are not nullable).

Is there any way to save an empty/null embedded object?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Please create an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC

Comment: Looks like this already happened: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-364

Comment: thanks, @JensSchauder. This is my ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is documented in [DATAJDBC-364](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-364) and fixed for the 1.1 M4 milestone.
Please note that this is related to [DATAJDBC-374](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-374) which will make it configurable how to load those embedded entities.